# How to disable Remmina Remote Desktop automatic shortcuts?

Tags: 12.04, remote-desktop, remmina, shortcut-keys

I noticed that Remmina Remote Desktop comes installed by default in 12.04.  This is great because I have used it in the past and really enjoy it.  Anyways, there is a little problem.  When I am doing RDP connection to my Windows 7 machine, it seems that windows shortcuts are enabled by default, without pressing ctrl or alt or the windows button.  Every time I type the letter "f", the search window pops up in the windows environment, and the text "f" is never entered into the email.  As you could see, writing an email or editing other text is almost impossible like this.

Has anybody had any experience with this?  Know how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. My solution was to use Windows-Key on my keyboard to deactivate the shortcuts. With Windows-Key + F it seems to can be activated again. Try it.
Additional: The Num-block (NumPad) is working/active only if the Num-Button/Key is deactivated.
I hope it helps.

Regards
Alexej

Comment: yes i found that same thing worked just by random chance, thanks for the help!